# Looping through webpages when href does not exist for certain pages

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, href

I am collecting reviews from the web. Some products have multiple pages of reviews; others have only one page. With the help of a few people here, I have written a code that basically makes the scraper clicks on the "next page" link when there is one.

My problem is that when there is just one page of reviews, there is no link to click and the scraper keeps waiting. I would like the program to see if the next-page link exists: if it does, click on it, and if it does not, go back to the top of the loop.

Here is my code:

```
for url in list_urls:
  while True:
    raw_html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html)

#See if the "next page" link exists: if it does not, go back to the top of the loop
    href_test = soup.find('div', id='company_reviews_pagination')
    if href_test == None:
       break

#If next-page link exists, click on it
    elif href_test != None:
       last_link = soup.find('div',id='company_reviews_pagination').find_all('a')[-1]
       if last_link.text.startswith('Next'):
          next_url_parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(last_link['href'])
          url = urllib.parse.urlunparse(#code to define the "next-page" url - that part works!)
       else:
          break
```

So far, it does not give me errors, but the program is not running, it keeps waiting. What am I doing wrong? Should I try with a "try" statement to specifically handle this exception?

Many thanks in advance. Any guidance is extremely appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the actual URL in order to reproduce the problem and help you? Thanks.

Comment: Got it. Nothing that a good old "try / except" cannot fix. ;)
Thanks @alecxe for the willingness to help.

Answer (score 0):

So here is how I fixed it. Instead of playing with "if the link exists conditions", I used try/except:

```
    try:
       last_link = soup.find('div', id='company_reviews_pagination').find_all('a')[-1]
       if last_link.text.startswith('Next'):
         next_url_parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(last_link['href'])
         url = urllib.parse.urlunparse(#code to find the next-page link )

       else:
         break
    except :
       break
```